# Adding conditional check to display information in Angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I am displaying the following information in angular 8 application. I need to display only the `partnerName` if it exists.

```
<h1>Financial Game Plan<br>of <span>{{ name }} and {{ partnerName }} </span> for {{ currentDateString }}</h1>
```

I have done the following. Could you let me know if it is correct?

TS

```
 this.name = factFindService.dataModel.client.firstName + ' ' + factFindService.dataModel.client.lastName;
      if(factFindService.dataModel.partner) {
        this.partnerName = factFindService.dataModel.partner.firstName + ' ' + factFindService.dataModel.partner.lastName;
      }
```

HTML

```
 <h1>Financial Game Plan<br>of <span>{{ name }} <span *ngIf="partnerName"> and {{ partnerName }} </span> </span> for {{ currentDateString }}</h1>
```

Comment: The one issue that I see is that and styling is not looking similar to of as it could be probably because of is not in the span tag